# how do I get the onEdit function to run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am making my own D&D sheet for my friends. I would like this to be as cool and as complex as possible. Currently the onEdit function isn't even triggering
. I am trying to hide certain rows based on J3, if J3 = 1 then row 7 will be hidden. In the future I will hide rows 7-10, if J3 >= 2 then it will show rows 7-10. When it changes nothing happens. Please help.

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Actions')
    var status = sheet.getRange('J3').getValue();
    if (status == 1) {
      sheet.hideRows(7);
    } else {
    if (status >= 2) {
      sheet.showRows(7);
    }
  }
  Logger.log('yay you did it')}
```

Comment: `for( i=3 ; i=lastRow ; i++) {` what does it mean? Explain.

Comment: What are you doing to trigger the onEdit function? How do you know that it's not being triggered? What is the purpose of  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`?

Comment: The onEdit function is being used with J3 which is the current level. If the level = 1 then hide the level 2 features. I know it's not triggering because every time I change it nothing happens, and when I run the code it never stops running. I also meant to delete that `var ss`. I'm actually not sure the entire purpose of `for( i=3 ; i=lastRow ; i++)  {` I am new to this so I looked up a scenario that was answered, put my own credentials for the problem in. Then debugged it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet()
  if(sh.getName()!='Actions')return;
  var status=sh.getRange('J3').getValue();
  if (status==1) {
    sh.hideRows(7);
  }else if(status>=2){
    sh.showRows(7);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it, Sorry I can't up-vote you